# "Never ever" sentence construction

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

"But they rejected me, because they say that in those woods was never seen a single wolf ever." - Is this use of never ever correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to comment on how correct it is because the entire sentence sounds very poetic and antiquated. Expressions like "was never seen" are not in common usage in modern English however it is commonly heard in movies about the early 1900's and so. If someone made this statement in everyday speech, I would assume he was quoting some old literature and consequently, the validity of it loses relevance.

If the statement was made in earnest, I would assume he really wanted to emphasize "never". I do not think it is technically correct in modern English though and it wouldn't naturally be comprehensible.

Comment: I want to use this sentence in a book and I'm not native speaker so I don't know whether use it or not. Do you know any alternative which I could use?

Comment: "But they rejected me saying that no one has ever seen a single wolf in those woods" perhaps? IT would be easier with more context. I can't determine if "because" is appropriate without knowing what happened before.

Comment: Thanks for help, I really appreciate it. I think this suits my sentence better than context with because.